# Formdata not added properly to the post request

Tags: javascript, typescript, request, fetch-api, form-data

I am trying to post form data from a react-application using fetch:

```
export async function createPublicTask(data: CreatePublicTask) : Promise<Response> {
  const url = new URL(`${process.env.REACT_APP_GRAPH_URL_API_PUBLIC}/publictasks`);
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('createPublicTask', JSON.stringify(data));
  const headers = {'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=17482859224952074240'};

  return await fetch(url.toString(), {headers, method: "POST", body: formData})
}
```

In the network tab, I get:

[image: Form data seems to be missing]

In the bottom line you see Form Data(0). It looks like the FormData-object is empty. If I expand the line and click view source, I get:
[image]

The data seems to be there. What am I doing wrong?

It seems to work fine i Postman, using the same headers and the same field with data:
[image: The same request i Postman]

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer: Drop the Content-Type in the headers. In this case dropping the headers at all, solved the problem.

Comment: I don't know why your question was marked down, but thank you for posting and also following up with your own answer. I had the same problem and your answer solved it for me. It would be interesting to know why this is the case, but in the meantime - thank you.